# How to "correctly" copy a types.SimpleNamespace object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces, copy

I was expecting to be able to do something like:

```
a = SimpleNamespace(x='test')
b = a.copy()
```

or maybe:

```
b = SimpleNamespace(a)
```

My current solution, which seems to work fine is

```
b = SimpleNamespace(**a.__dict__)
```

But it looks somewhat hacky. Is there a more "correct" way?

I don't need a deep copy.

Comment: Your current solution looks perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: @khelwood Idk, asking for `__dict__` seems a little fishy. Maybe not.

Comment: If it bothers you, why not `b = SimpleNamespace(**vars(a))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to use do a deepcopy of a SimpleNamespace. A simple and easy to read way is to use the copy module.

```
new_namespace = copy.copy(namespace)
```

or

```
new_namespace = copy.deepcopy(namespace)
```

depending on what you need.